# javascript DOM element counter

Tags: javascript, dom, counter

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/WSEbB.png)I have a button that permit to add checkbox element dynamically,

```js
function addCheck() {
    var checkinput = document.createElement('input')

    var form = document.getElementById('form')

    check.setAttribute('type', 'checkbox')
    check.setAttribute('name', 'check')

    form.appendChild(checkinput)
}
```

I want to count how many the user created a new Element whenever he presses the button

```
    var count=0;
    function addCheck() {

      let pos= document.getElementById("dynamic-checkbox");

 var checkinput = document.createElement("input");

  check.setAttribute("type", "checkbox");

  check.setAttribute("name", "rep");
    pos.appendChild(check);
    count++;
```

Comment: Just add a counter and increment it on button click

Comment: So, create a variable to hold the count (`let count = 0`), and increment that counter at the end of the function (`count++`).

Comment: yes, how i could do it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use [`querySelectorAll()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/querySelectorAll) by passing the input type as the selector and take the length:

```
var count = form.querySelectorAll('input[type=checkbox]').length;
```

```js
var form= document.getElementById("form");
function addCheck() {   
  var checkinput = document.createElement("input");

  checkinput.setAttribute("type", "checkbox");
  checkinput.setAttribute("name", "check");

  form.appendChild(checkinput); 
  var count = form.querySelectorAll('input[type=checkbox]').length;
  console.log('Total Checkbox: ' +count);
}
```

```html
<form id="form"></form>

<button type="btn" onclick="addCheck()">Add</button>
```

You can also maintain a variable as counter:

```js
var form= document.getElementById("form");
var count = 0;
function addCheck() {   
  
  var checkinput = document.createElement("input");

  checkinput.setAttribute("type", "checkbox");
  checkinput.setAttribute("name", "check");

  form.appendChild(checkinput); 
  count++;
  console.log('Total Checkbox: ' +count);
}
```

```html
<form id="form"></form>

<button type="btn" onclick="addCheck()">Add</button>
```

Comment: Seems kind of overkill to use querySelectorAll every time the user clicks. Why not simply have an external count variable?

Answer (score 1):

Here's an alternative to using a counter variable, or checking the length of the number of existing elements in the DOM. You initially set up the counter element with the `textContent` set as zero, and then with each call of the function set that content to whatever the current content is (coerced from a string to a number) plus 1.

```js
// Cache the elements we reuse
const form = document.querySelector('form');
const button = document.querySelector('button');
const counter = document.querySelector('#counter');

button.addEventListener('click', addCheck, false);

function addCheck() {
  const checkinput = document.createElement('input');
  checkinput.setAttribute('type', 'checkbox');
  checkinput.setAttribute('name', 'check');
  form.appendChild(checkinput);
  counter.textContent = Number(counter.textContent) + 1;
}
```

```html
<div id="counter">0</div>
<button>Add checkbox</button>
<form></form>
```

Answer (score 0):

Just add a counter and increment it on button click. While setting attribute you have used the name of the variable in which the element is stored as check, but it should be checkinput

```js
var count = 0;
var total=0;

function addCheck() {
  var checkinput = document.createElement('input')

  var form = document.getElementById('form')

  checkinput.setAttribute('type', 'checkbox')
  checkinput.setAttribute('name', 'check')

  form.appendChild(checkinput)
  count++;
  total=count+2;
  console.log('Number of checkboxes created by the user:' + count)
  console.log(  'Total checkboxes in the form:' + total)
}
```

```html
<button onclick="addCheck()">click</button>
<form id="form">
<input type="checkbox" name="check">
<input type="checkbox" name="check">
</form>
```

Comment: it works but add a pair number for the first press it gives 1 in the second it gives 3

Comment: I lost you on **add a pair number for the first press**

Comment: means it's kinda =+ 2

Comment: But why you want to add 2 on a single click, as I suppose on one click only one checkbox is created

Comment: this is the point I want to add it point by point but when I tried ur code this is what it gave me(it adds one checkbox but the count is wrong)

Comment: In the snippet it is working just fine. Can you show a working example for the same in your question

Comment: i eddited the post, by the way I have 2 existing checkbox created by html - not dynamic

Comment: Check the edits. Also added the 2 checkboxes which were present before

Comment: enter to the image decription please

Comment: in total there are 3 checkbox not 4

Comment: There might be something else in your code interfering with it as in the snippet its working fine